# Payment Method Sales/Order grid - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, order-grid

We load the following code to show the payment method inside the Sales/Order grid.

But this displays the payment code and we want to display the payment title.

How can we change our current code to show the title?

CODE:

```
$select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));
```

CODE filterPaymentMethod:

```
public function filterPaymentMethod($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $collection->getSelect()->having(
        "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");

    return;
}
```

Comment: use `additional_information` column instead of `method` column. in this column payment title is saved like - {"method_title":"Check \/ Money order"}

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Thanks! Tried this but I can not get the right result, what should be the right code to use?

Comment: which file you are using this code ?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat We use a custom module for this, that loads the code. We tried this: `$select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('method_title' => 'additional_information'));`

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat We use this module: https://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/

Comment: @HenkZ, try my answer please, put your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Try below way

you can use like this to get the payment method in your custom module or override core files  `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
         $collection->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','method');
         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
         // end here //
    }
```

and in grid

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

 $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel)
        {
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
        }

        $this->addColumn('method', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
                        'index' => 'method',
                        'filter_index' => 'payment.method',
                        'type'  => 'options',
                        'width' => '70px',
                        'options' => $methods,
                ));
        // End here
    }
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But we can not use this, because we load the code using a custom module. So we need to modify the current code.

Comment: then you should put above code into your custom module I mean only _prepareCollection and _prepareColumns methods

Comment: Thanks, we use the module: https://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/. How to implement your code into this?

Comment: you can just find sales order grid code in atwix and just replace or append above code as your need OR override atwix's sales order grid file into your custom module

Comment: I do not really get it, how to extend this code. Can you show me what I need to edit?

Comment: Atwix uses by observer, if you are using Atwix module code only for display payment method then I think you don't need it just try to create fresh module or remove code which is display payment method code and try with my code which I mentioned in answer I don't know by Atwix's observer way Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need column renderer functionality, here is just basic idea how you can do it, (**this code is not tested**) -

in your module you need to use `renderer` param in file `extendedgrid.xml` like below --

```
<action method="addColumnAfter">
         <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
         <arguments>
            <header>Payment Method</header>
            <index>payment_method</index>
            <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
            <renderer>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Renderer</renderer>
            <type>text</type>
         </arguments>
        <after>shipping_name</after>
</action>
```

and create file 'Renderer.php' at path  `Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid`

```
<?php

    class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Renderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
   {    
       public function render(Varien_Object $row)
       {
          $paymentMethodCode =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
         /* $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods(); // will get all active payment method*/

          $payments = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();  // get all available payment method

        
          $paymentTitle = '';
          foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel)
          {
              if($paymentMethodCode == $paymentCode)
              {
                 $paymentTitle =Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
              
              }
              
           }

           return $paymentTitle;
        }
    }
```

Reference link for renderer functionality :-

> http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/add-custom-column-and-get-custom-renderer-value-in-magento-grid/
>
> http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid

**EDIT:-**  in case if you use block file instead of layout file for column in grid, use below function to apply filter on `renderer` column.

```
public function filterPaymentMethod($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }
    
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                    'sales_flat_order_payment',           
                    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',
                    array('method'))
                 ->where("sales_flat_order_payment.method like ?", "%$value%");

        return $collection;
    }
```

**Edit2:-** replace your function `filterPaymentMethod` in `observer.php` file with below code --

```
public function filterPaymentMethod($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $payments =  Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getAllMethods();

        $codeToFilter ='';
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            
            if (stripos($paymentTitle, $value) !== false && !$codeTomatch) {
                $codeTomatch = $paymentCode;
            }
        }
 
        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                    'sales_flat_order_payment',           
                    'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',
                    array('method'))
                 ->where("sales_flat_order_payment.method like ?", "%$codeToFilter%");

        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That does seem to work, but the requested payment method should also be active to show. Will to be possible to display the title even if the method is disabled?

Comment: Yes, because line `Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title')` is fetching payment title from DB regardless it is active or not.

Comment: Great, how to edit the code, so that it will be displayed, even if disabled?

Comment: as suggested in above answer you need to modify `extendedgrid.xml` file of your module and follow next step as suggested.

Comment: Yes, we already did modify extendedgrid.xml. That part works perfect, but due to the line  `$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();` it only loads active payment methods. And we want to show it always, even if disabled. So how to edit this?

Comment: try to use `getAllMethods` instead of `getActiveMethods`.

Comment: Your Welcome, Happy Codingg :)

Comment: Thanks, the only problem we now have is that the selector/sorter at the top does not work. It still sorts based on the code, not on the new title. How to edit this? So I guess we need to edit: <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>?

Comment: you need to use another param called `filter_condition_callback` just like `renderer`.  check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149409/filter-in-grid-with-custom-renderer) how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have no idea how to include it in our current code/edit. Do you have a good solution to implement it in our current code?

Comment: I do get the part of <filter_condition_callback>Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Filter</filter_condition_callback>. But what code do we need to add to get the right filter and at what path?

Comment: no, not like this. It will require different approach than in case of `renderer`. for this it will require  review of magento code. you have used layout file to add column in grid instead of block file thats why its a bit complicated and tricky as well.

Comment: Almost there, can you help me out with the last part? We need the following correct: `    public function filterPaymentMethod($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->having(
            "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");

        return;
    }`

Comment: are you using block file this time instead of layout file ?

Comment: Yes, we changed it back from layout to the data.php file. So we added: 'filter_condition_callback' => array('Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer', 'filterPaymentMethod'). But now we need to get the right sorting code

Comment: ok can you please post code your function `filterPaymentMethod` in question

Comment: Yes, see my edit in the question, for the current code. But we need to change it from SKU to the new payment code.

Comment: check updated answer for `filterPaymentMethod` please, its not tested but should work

Comment: Thanks, sadly I get the following error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order_payment' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON `sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id WHERE (sales_order_payment like '%Creditcard%')`

Comment: @HenkZ Please use ""sales_order_payment.method" instead of ""sales_order_payment"

Comment: That does not seem to work, then we get: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_order_payment.method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON `sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id WHERE (sales_order_payment.method like '%Creditcard%')~

Comment: use updated function `filterPaymentMethod` .

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: Well the error is gone, but the sorting does not work. It does not show any results, when we enter a value. When searching for the payment code, we do get the results.

Comment: dump sql query in above function ` filterPaymentMethod` using `echo $collection->getSelect(); die();`

Comment: That shows: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`

Comment: where did you applied this code ?  apply this code ` echo $collection->getSelect(); die();` just before return statement in function `filterPaymentMethod`  it should show a long query

Comment: No we did not, sorry. We now get: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order_payment`.`method` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_payment.method like '%Creditcard%')

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: run your dumped query directly in DB and check result.

Comment: @HenkZ, got working ?

Comment: Thanks, I check that query in the DB but got 0 results.So it still does not work. I guess we are not looking in the right table or row. When checking the payment code it does show results

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Do you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Can you help me out with this last part? I still can not get it done.

Comment: let me know where you stuck ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Well, the problem is that the sorting is not working based on the payment title, the sorting still works based on the payment code. So it seems that the last part of the code for filter is not working well.

Comment: ok, can you provide me zip file of your whole module what you have done so far ?
I will check it on my end.

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat How can I sent the zip?

Comment: upload your zip on any URL or use dropbox.

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat See the zip: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h99wuapt16l15ru/Module_StackExchange.zip?dl=0

Comment: @HenkZ, i got chance to installed your module, I found that filter is working. can you please explain what problem you are getting now ?

Comment: @HenkZ, I have changed some thing in function `filterPaymentMethod` in observer.php file. check edit2 section in answer and let me know if it does not work

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Thanks a lot! I tried the new code, but it still does not work. In this case it does not change any results, so it does not apply the filter. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat Still having the same issue, can you help us out?

Comment: @HenkZ, I am not getting what issue you are facing now after my code correction